# how to write rows qtreewidget in a file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I want to save/write each row of QtreeWidget in a file(.xml or .txt or .xlsx or ...).

note: the rows are dynamically added.

sample image of qtreewidget in link:
Click [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fddgobkiprc33d.cloudfront.net%2F02e66736-c71e-480c-8c56-fabd4ef3eed8.PNG&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.qt.io%2Ftopic%2F90460%2Fwhy-is-there-a-space-in-qtreewidget&docid=AeGXEUMFrFV4oM&tbnid=0RP2TFcH8nqDIM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwia9PHv6eriAhUB3qQKHVfTCdkQMwiMASg-MD4..i&w=277&h=193&client=opera&bih=668&biw=1326&q=qtreewidget&ved=0ahUKEwia9PHv6eriAhUB3qQKHVfTCdkQMwiMASg-MD4&iact=mrc&uact=8")!

Answer (score 0):

If your treeWidget doesnt have ChildItems like in the example picture than this is quite easy to solve:

```
   void myClass::on_pushButton_clicked()
   {
    QString sResult = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < ui.treeWidget->topLevelItemCount(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ui.treeWidget->columnCount(); j++) //fix: j++
        {
            sResult += ui.treeWidget->topLevelItem(i)->text(j) + "\t";  // a Tab Character added for better readability.
        }
        sResult += "\n";   //new Line
    }


    QFile file("myFile.txt");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << sResult << endl;
    }

    }
```